# Multiple testing correction on non-normal data with dependent tests

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I have 8 continuous variables in a small sample (n=10)

with mostly a non-normal distribution.

I perform 4 Wilcoxon signed-rank tests on the 4 variable pairs.

The variables are strongly dependent across pairs.

I was wandering which correction of multiple comparison I should apply as the Bonferroni & Dunn procedures seem to be too conservative taking the dependence of variables into account.

Thanks a lot for your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Bonferroni correction is just one of the many methods (perhaps the most famous and conservative one) proposed for controlling family-wise error rate (FWER). Be sure to read more about other methods in the Wikipedia page for [FWER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate)

If you are fine with the Wilcoxon singed-rank test (given its assumptions and what it looks for) - read the Wikipedia page for [singed-rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test), you could perform permutation given the small sample size that you have. You can perform as many permutations as you want to get a good sense of your null distribution.